# Magento 2- Admin Reorder of Gift card order with custom giftcard amount not working after cancelling the order

Tags: magento2

Customer ordered a Gift card with custom amount(**custom_giftcard_amount**).Admin canceled  that order and then trying to Reorder from backend.  But it is not working.Getting this error "**Please specify a gift card amount.**"

The Scenario is working for fixed amount(**giftcard_amount**)

**Note**

I found the issue. After admin canceled  the order, I checked  the **product_options** column of **sales_order_item** tables. **giftcard_amount** and **custom_giftcard_amount** field is not there for custom amount order items.  Anybody have an idea about this?